# Alias lost within script

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I want to alias the gnu-date `gdate` to `date` when a program runs on mac

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(uname) -eq 'Darwin' ]]; then
    alias date="gdate"
    echo 'you are on a mac!'
    type date
fi
# rest of the program
```

Given this code, if i run int directly on a terminal it prints:

```
you are on a mac!
date is an alias for gdate
```

But if I run the script itself like `./test.sh` in prints:

```
you are on a mac!
date is /bin/date
```

Why is the alias not being applied from the script?

Comment: try:  source test.sh

Comment: If you set `shopt -s expand_aliases` then aliases are expanded in non-interactive shells, but chepner's answer has more uses than just as an alias replacement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, aliases are not expanded in a non-interactive shell. Use a function instead.

```
if [[ $(name) -eq Darwin ]]; then
   date () { gdate "$@"; }
   echo 'you are on a mac!'
   type date
fi
```

Comment: this worked like charm. However I had to put `$@` to pass gdate the argument list.  Would it work with just the `@`?

Comment: No; that's a typo on my part. `"$@"` is required.

Answer (score 2):

Using a function will in many cases be the right solution.  Anytime you have a function-based solution, do that.

However, there are things you cannot do with a function, most notably anything having to do with modifying the positional parameters of the calling context, and you can force alias expansion in a shell script by enabling the corresponding option :

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

You have to be aware of and control what aliases exist in your script to avoid unexpected behavior.

Comment: that's great, and since I'm working with zsh this solves a couple common `weird behaviors`.